# How to change the font for a dojo toolbarbutton?

Tags: cordova, fonts, dojo

I am using dojo toolkit for developing a iphone app.
I already imported the Webding font into the phonegap project but I don't know how to change the font of a toolbarbutton.
Can anyone help?

greets
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overwriting the dojo css mblToolBarButton class in your css file with this:

```
.mblToolBarButton {
line-height: 19px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana; // Your font, try system fonts first
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;

}
```

Comment: doesnt work for my custom font, only for the system fonts. After googling a while i gave up and inserted an icon. thx anyway

Comment: So the initial question of how to change the font of a toolbarbutton is answered ?